# How to make enemy sprites collide and not mesh together when moving

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

EDIT: Please stop referring me to the bird colliding with a rock game, my problem is no where near his. I have the player able to collide with and not go through the walls in my game, but the code does not transfer to the zombies. The zombies do not collide and rub against each other, they just slide into each other and become one block. Read my explanation below please <3

So I'm working on a game in pygame where zombies move toward the player as the player shoots them down (I know, original, right?) But the code I have to detect the zombies collision with each other does not work in any practical way and without it the zombies simply move toward the player and mesh together into one zombie block. What can I change in the zombie's code to make them not move into each other as they close in to eat my brains?

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.pos_x = self.rect.x = random.randrange(35, screen_width - 35)
        self.pos_y = self.rect.y = random.randrange(35, screen_height - 135)

        # How Zombies move towards player

    def update(self):
        zombie_vec_x = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        zombie_vec_y = self.rect.y - player.rect.y
        vec_length = math.sqrt(zombie_vec_x ** 2 + zombie_vec_y ** 2)
        zombie_vec_x = (zombie_vec_x / vec_length) * 1 # These numbers determine
        zombie_vec_y = (zombie_vec_y / vec_length) * 1 # zombie movement speed

        self.pos_x -= zombie_vec_x
        self.pos_y -= zombie_vec_y

        self.rect.x = self.pos_x
        self.rect.y = self.pos_y


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, sprites_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.rect.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.rect.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
            elif self.rect.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            else:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom
```

This is the entire zombie code, the current collision code is at the bottom, starting at `block_hit_list =`. Any insight on how to correct this or explain how collision coding works would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Sorry, but no, my problem is very different from that one. Still looking for help, thanks!

Comment: Okay, then -- that does clarify things better for me; sorry.  So what *do* you expect that final block of code to do?  This says that if anything collides with me, I should snuggle up to it, side by side.  This makes me think that all the zombies will form a large block of zombies.  Are you saying that they overlap and merge?

Comment: Have you tried tracking the control and data flow of that loop?  How many hits are there, and what happens to the coordinates as you move through the block?  Most of all, when is "update" called?  Is it called on only the player, or is this called on every zombie in turn?  If it's on every zombie, the problem is that you have treated only the zombie pair, and not *all* zombies at once.  The "self" zombie is adjusted against each contact zombie in turn, which means that only the last one counts -- the "self" zombie is free to overlap any of the other zombies in the block_hit_list.

Comment: @Prune ah I see, so I don't want the zombies to snuggle up together, I just want them to not be able to move through each other -- I want them to be "solid" objects. The update function is called throughout the main loop so that the zombies will constantly follow the player in the game. What would be a good thing to do to fix up my code to make it work the way I want?

Comment: @Prune And the code presented above does make them clump up, when I remove the code that's when they overlap onto each other

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain of the code details, since you haven't described your coordinate system in detail.  However, the main point is that you have to find a safe place for the current zombie to move, a place without other zombies in it.  This really requires you to work from the most restricted area to the least.  Can you sort the zombies into some spatial order?  Perhaps iterate through your zombie list from lower-left to upper right?

Given that, each zombie has to check for a spot with respect to *all* of the others, not merely getting out of the way of each other zombie in turn.  You have to consider the x and y directions more holistically.  I think this could well work, depending on the movement speed (can a zombie take a step more than half a zombie width?).

```
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, sprites_list, False)
    if self.rect.x > 0:
        self.rect.right = min(block.rect.left for block in block_hit_list)
    else:
        self.rect.left = max(block.rect.right for block in block_hit_list)

    if self.rect.y > 0:
        self.rect.bottom = min(block.rect.top for block in block_hit_list)
    else:
        self.rect.top = max(block.rect.bottom for block in block_hit_list)
```

Note that I'm handling *both* coordinates, not just one -- I'm assuming that a zombie can move diagonally.  I'm not sure I have the directions matched up properly in your coordinate system: if self.rect.x > 0, do I want the *most* positive zombie's left edge?  I don't know whether left > right or top > bottom in your coordinate system.  Please test and adjust as necessary.

Also, please temporarily insert a tracing print statement in each branch: display at least the x/y coordinates before and after.

Does this get you moving toward a solution?

Comment: It looks like this does what my code does, the zombies jump all over when they touch each other and it's kinda spastic. I appreciate the feedback for sure, but it looks like I'll still be on the hunt. Is there any other information I can give that would help you with a suggestion?

Comment: You can specify what it is you *do* want.  The code you originally posted moves a touched zombie out of the way of each other zombie in turn, but keeps only the minimal change to avoid the last zombie in the list.  The code in my answer draws a rectangle around *all* the touching zombies, and then moves the "self" zombie to a convenient corner-to-corner touch.  If you want realistic movement, you need to think more thoroughly from the mass perspective.  For instance, if four zombies surround and squeeze the first zombie in your "update" list, what should that one do?

Comment: Neither your code nor mine handles that situation: yours gets him clear of the last surrounding zombie by overlapping the opposite one, and ignoring the other two.  Mine teleports him outside their range.  If you want realistic motion, you need to redesign the block that calls update. For instance, identify a starting point and let that zombie claim his spot.  Working outward from there, adjust each zombie to a nearby position that does not conflict with a "claimed" zombie -- but is allowed to overlap any other zombie.  Continue until all zombies have claimed.

Comment: Alright so here's what I want to happen: When a zombie moves into the path of another zombie, I want the zombies to continue moving towards the player but not have them move into each other. I want them to rub against each other but not merge into each other, just like if two people in real life walked into each other. They don't occupy the same physical space, they'd just run into each other right? So I want the zombies, when they collide with one another, to rub against each other as they group up and move to the same location, but not occupy the same physical space.

Comment: That's a *much* better start.  Now you have to decide: are you going to move the zombies one at a time, resolving conflicts before going to the next one; or do you want to move them all and then resolve conflicts?  In the latter case, you have to decide somehow which zombie gets to claim new space and which yields.  In the former case, you have to order the zombies well -- such as sorting them by distance to the player, moving the closest zombie first (should be little or no conflict there).  This requires changes to code you haven't posted here -- and perhaps a new posting.

Comment: Ok, do you have any ideas oh what that code may look like? This whole idea seems a lot more complex than I originally thought haha :P I have the player able to move and collide into walls just as you'd expect when playing any game but the code for zombies running into other zombies doesn't work at all when trying to use the same concept as the player/walls. Maybe because they are moving sprites so the way they collide and reposition is probably a lot more complex

Comment: Yes, it's a lot more complex: the zombies have to worry about each other zombie, all moving targets.  I outlined the algorithm for you above; the next step is your job.  Sort the zombies by distance from the player and move them one at a time, closest one first.  If he hits another zombie who's already moved (and claimed his spot), adjust as appropriate.  This is not trivial, but if you break the task down, it can be straightforward.

Comment: As always, code a few lines at a time.  Put in print statements to see that you're getting what you expect.  When you get stuck, post a new question.  I think we've moved past this one.

Comment: I agree, thank you for your time and willingness to help me :)